# How to use feature hasher to convert non-numerical discrete data so that it can be passed to SVM?

Tags: python, numpy, machine-learning, scikit-learn, feature-extraction

I am trying to use the CRX dataset from the UCI Machine Learning repository. This particular dataset contains some features which are not continuous variables. Therefore I need to convert them into numerical values before they can be passed to an SVM.

I initially looked into using the one-hot decoder, which takes integer values and converts them into matrices (e.g. if a feature has three possible values, 'red' 'blue' and 'green', this would be converted into three binary features: 1,0,0 for 'red', '0,1,0 for 'blue' and 0,0,1 for 'green'. This would be ideal for my needs, except for the fact that it only can deal with integer features.

```
def get_crx_data(debug=False):

    with open("/Volumes/LocalDataHD/jt306/crx.data", "rU") as infile:
        features_array = []
        reader = csv.reader(infile,dialect=csv.excel_tab)
        for row in reader:
            features_array.append(str(row).translate(None,"[]'").split(","))
        features_array = np.array(features_array)
        print features_array.shape
        print features_array[0]
        labels_array = features_array[:,15]
        features_array = features_array[:,:15]
        print features_array.shape
        print labels_array.shape


        print("FeatureHasher on frequency dicts")

        hasher = FeatureHasher(n_features=44)
        X = hasher.fit_transform(line for line in features_array)

        print X.shape



get_crx_data()
```

This returns

```
Reading CRX data from disk
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File"/Volumes/LocalDataHD/PycharmProjects/FeatureSelectionPython278/Crx2.py", line 38, in <module>

get_crx_data()
  File "/Volumes/LocalDataHD/PycharmProjects/FeatureSelectionPython278/Crx2.py", line 32, in get_crx_data

X = hasher.fit_transform(line for line in features_array)

File "/Volumes/LocalDataHD/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sklearn/base.py", line 426, in fit_transform
    return self.fit(X, **fit_params).transform(X)

File "/Volumes/LocalDataHD/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sklearn/feature_extraction/hashing.py", line 129, in transform
    _hashing.transform(raw_X, self.n_features, self.dtype)

File "_hashing.pyx", line 44, in sklearn.feature_extraction._hashing.transform (sklearn/feature_extraction/_hashing.c:1649)

File "/Volumes/LocalDataHD/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sklearn/feature_extraction/hashing.py", line 125, in <genexpr>
    raw_X = (_iteritems(d) for d in raw_X)

File "/Volumes/LocalDataHD/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sklearn/feature_extraction/hashing.py", line 15, in _iteritems
    return d.iteritems() if hasattr(d, "iteritems") else d.items()

AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'items'

(690, 16)
['0' ' 30.83' ' 0' ' u' ' g' ' w' ' v' ' 1.25' ' 1' ' 1' ' 1' ' 0' ' g'
 ' 202' ' 0' ' +']
(690, 15)
(690,)
FeatureHasher on frequency dicts

Process finished with exit code 1


How can I use feature hashing (or an alternative method) to convert this data from classes (some of which are strings, others are discrete numerical values) into data which can be handled by an SVM? I have also looked into using one-hot coding, but that only takes integers as input.
```

Comment: Could you paste the full stack trace? That way we can get a sense of which of these lines is causing the error.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. Done, and added a bit more info.

Comment: At first glance, shouldn't it be simply `X = hasher.fit_transform(features_array)`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The issue is that the `FeatureHasher` object expects each row of input to have a particular structure -- or really, one of three different [possible structures](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_extraction.FeatureHasher.html). The first possibility is a dictionary of `feature_name:value` pairs. The second is a list of `(feature_name, value)` tuples. And the third is a flat list of `feature_name`s. In the first two cases, the feature names are mapped to columns in the matrix, and given values are stored at those columns for each row. In the last, the presence or absence of a feature in the list is implicitly understood as a `True` or `False` value. Here are some simple, concrete examples:

```
>>> hasher = sklearn.feature_extraction.FeatureHasher(n_features=10,
...                                                   non_negative=True,
...                                                   input_type='dict')
>>> X_new = hasher.fit_transform([{'a':1, 'b':2}, {'a':0, 'c':5}])
>>> X_new.toarray()
array([[ 1.,  2.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  5.,  0.,  0.]])
```

This illustrates the default mode -- what the `FeatureHasher` will expect if you don't pass `input_type`, as in your original code. As you can see, the expected input is a list of dictionaries, one for each input sample or row of data. Each dictionary contains an arbitrary number of feature names, mapped to values for that row.

The output, `X_new`, contains a sparse representation of the array; calling `toarray()` returns a new copy of the data as a vanilla `numpy` array.

If you want to pass pairs of tuples instead, pass `input_type='pairs'`. Then you can do this:

```
>>> hasher = sklearn.feature_extraction.FeatureHasher(n_features=10,
...                                                   non_negative=True,
...                                                   input_type='pair')
>>> X_new = hasher.fit_transform([[('a', 1), ('b', 2)], [('a', 0), ('c', 5)]])
>>> X_new.toarray()
array([[ 1.,  2.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  5.,  0.,  0.]])
```

And finally, if you just have boolean values, you don't have to pass values explicitly at all -- the `FeatureHasher` will simply assume that if a feature name is present, then its value is `True` (represented here as the floating point value `1.0`).

```
>>> hasher = sklearn.feature_extraction.FeatureHasher(n_features=10,
...                                                   non_negative=True,
...                                                   input_type='string')
>>> X_new = hasher.fit_transform([['a', 'b'], ['a', 'c']])
>>> X_new.toarray()
array([[ 1.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  0.,  0.]])
```

Unfortunately, your data doesn't seem to consistently be in any one of these formats. However, it shouldn't be *too* hard to modify what you have to fit the `'dict'` or `'pair'` format. Let me know if you need help with that; in that case, please say more about the format of the data you're trying to convert.